# Как подключить два файла

Tags: java, android

Подключаю один файл вот так, а как подключить 2 сразу или более

```
public List<String> getTextFromRaw() {
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStream inputStream, inputStream1;
    BufferedReader bufRead;
    try {
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.stm);
        bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
            arr.add(line);
            count++;
            if (count == 20) {
                break;
            }
        }
        bufRead.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вынесите ид файла (в вашем случае это `R.raw.stm`) в параметры метода.

```
public List<String> getTextFromRaw(int fileId) {
    List<String> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    InputStream inputStream;
    BufferedReader bufRead;
    try {
        inputStream = getResources().openRawResource(fileId);
        bufRead = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line;
        int count = 0;
        while ((line = bufRead.readLine()) != null) {
            arr.add(line);
            count++;
            if (count == 20) {
                break;
            }
        }
        bufRead.close();
        inputStream.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Использование:

```
List<String> lines1 = getTextFromRaw(R.raw.stm);
List<String> lines2 = getTextFromRaw(R.raw.whatever);
```

Comment: как ещё и во втором файле допустим только первые 3 записи выводить? первом у меня первые 20 выводятся

Comment: Ну, также вынести число строк для вывода в параметр метода. То есть добавляете параметр: `getTextFromRaw(int fileId, int numberLinesToRead)` и используете его — заменяете `if (count == 20)` на `if (count == numberLinesToRead)`

Answer (score 1):

```
    Integer[] filesArray = {R.raw.file1, R.raw.file2, R.raw.file3, R.raw.file4};
    for (int i = 0; i < filesArray.length; i++) {
        getTextFromRaw(int fileId);//здесь по совету из ответа @diraria
    }
```